# Unbalanced parenthesis error with Regex

Tags: python, regex, json, scrapy

I am using the following regex to obtain all data from a website Javascript data source that is contained within the following character pattern

```
[[]]);
```

The code I am using is this:

```
regex = r'\[\[.*?\]]);'
        match2 = re.findall(regex, response.body, re.S)
        print match2
```

This is throwing up an error message of:

```
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

I think I am fairly safe in assuming that this is being caused by the closing bracket within my regex. How can I define the regex that I want without getting this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape those last parenthesis as well. Close square brackets outside a character class do not have to be escaped:

```
regex = r'\[\[.*?]]\);'
                   ^
```

If you are trying to obtain the content between the square brackets, use a capturing group here.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo [[bar]]); baz [[quz]]); not [[foobar]]'
>>> matches = re.findall(r'\[\[(.*?)]]\);', s, re.S)
>>> matches
['bar', 'quz']
```

Answer (score 2):

escape the last  `)` and `]`   `r'\[\[.*?\]\]\)`

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should be,

```
regex = r'\[\[.*?\]\]\);'
```

It would match literal `[[` symbols and the following characters upto the next `]]);` symbols.

**Explanation:**

- `\[\[` Matches the Literal `[[` symbols.
- `.*?` Matches any charcter zero or more times. `?` after `*` forces the regex engine to does a shortest (non-greedy) match.
- `\]\]\);` Matches the literal `]]);` symbols.